# What is the most efficient way of computing a confusion matrix from 2 logical vectors in R?

Tags: r

Given two logical vectors (i.e. Only with TRUE or FALSE values in R), both of length n (one vector is a prediction and the other one is the ground truth), what is the most efficient way to compute the true postives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives? True positives can be done easily just by doing `tp = pred & truth`. However, I don't think there are other logical operators in R that can directly help calculate the other statistics.

One obvious solution is to iterate through both vectors and just do cases (e.g. If prediction is FALSE and truth FALSE then increment true negatives by one) but I feel like there has to be a faster way. The true positive case is super nice because it can just be done with the AND operator which is vectorized (I think?).

EDIT: My bad, forgot to mention a couple important details: the vectors in my real data are in the hundred millions long and I need to compute confusion matrices about 30,000 times. The answers using table are useful as I had completely missed this option before but I'm afraid converting to factor and using table is too slow. I think the best option at this point would probably be to use Rcpp.

Comment: `table(pred, truth)`

Comment: @PKumar - if `pred` or `truth` is homogeneous, then `R` will not return a 2x2 table.  Better to convert to factors first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `confusionMatrix ()`function from `caret` package:

Code:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
confusionMatrix(
prediction <- factor(sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)),
ground_truth <- factor(sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 26 31
         1 20 23
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.49           
                 95% CI : (0.3886, 0.592)
    No Information Rate : 0.54           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.8650         
                                         
                  Kappa : -0.0087        
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.1614         
                                         
            Sensitivity : 0.5652         
            Specificity : 0.4259         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4561         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.5349         
             Prevalence : 0.4600         
         Detection Rate : 0.2600         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5700         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.4956         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the binary vectors to factors first,

```
pred = factor(pred, levels = c(F,T))
truth = factor(truth, levels = c(F,T))
```

this will ensure that a full 2x2 table is returned even when there are no instances of certain pairings.  The contingency table is calculated by

```
table(pred, truth)
```

converting to factor first will ensure that combinations with no instances will get a value of `0` in resulting table.  For example,

```
pred = rep(T, 10)
truth = rep(F, 10)

table(pred,truth)  # RETURNS A 1x1 TABLE 

pred = factor(pred, levels = c(F,T))
truth = factor(truth, levels = c(F,T))

table(pred,truth)  # RETURNS A 2x2 TABLE
```